# Best practice to store an iterator as a class member in C++

Tags: c++, oop, iterator

Is there a best practice to storing iterators as class members, given that the sequence or data structure being iterated over is unknown? I've written some code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, but the code doesn't compile.

```
#include <iterator>

class entity {
    std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, double>
        &it_begin_, &it_end_;
public:
    template <typename iter_type>
    entity(iter_type first, iter_type last) 
    : it_begin_(first)
    , it_end_(last) { } 

    // ... other implementation details
};

// example usage
int main() {
    std::vector<double> my_vec {1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0};
    entity my_entity(std::begin(my_vec), std::end(my_vec));
    // do stuff with entity
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Just to add some context, I'm trying to implement something along the lines of a [suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80592/converting-an-array-returning-function-to-a-lazy-evaluator) I received on the CodeReview site.

EDIT 2:

I've received some useful answers. Forgive me for not mentioning this detail but I thought it would be clear from the code: I want to specify (as part of the implementation detail) that I want to have a forward iterator, and that dereferencing it returns a `double`.

Comment: It's rarely if ever a good idea. Iterators are mostly local variables.

Comment: @EJP that's a fair point. If you'll indulge me, I'm trying to implement a suggestion from a CodeReview question I posted here: [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80592/converting-an-array-returning-function-to-a-lazy-evaluator].

Comment: I don't think it's any worse than storing a pointer. But treat iterators like pointers. You wouldn't store `int *&` in your class, but `int *`. So store the iterator by value.

Comment: @Nasser I was thinking more about Java iterators. C++ iterators are a somewhat different beast.

Comment: @NeilKirk good point. The reason I chose to store them by reference is because I didn't want `entity` to be a class template (as shown in the answers posted so far).

Answer (score 2):

Several things :

1. `std::begin(my_vec)` returns an iterator but entity class stores reference on it. If you want to use it that way, remove the reference `&`.
2. There is no problem to store iterator but an iterator is always relative to a container type like `vector::iterator`. Or you can template your class:

```
template < class iterator > 
class entity
{
  iterator _it, _end;
public:
  entity(iterator begin, iterator end): _it(begin), _end(end){}
  /* ... */
};

int main() {
  std::vector<double> my_vec {1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0};
  entity my_entity(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end());
  // do stuff with entity
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this will not compile, because you need to pass a template argument to `entity`. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Nasser Create a `make_entity` function template that deduces the arguments.

Comment: @Nasser : I think you need to go virtual and define a class C which declares virtuals increment and dereference. Then implement a templated class derived from C and as  0x499602D2 suggest, use a make_entity which will instanciate the correct C class using the arguments of the entity class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class template and a helper function template to do what you want to do.

```
template <typename iter_type>
class entity {
   iter_type it_begin_;
   iter_type it_end_;

   public:
   entity(iter_type first, iter_type last) 
      : it_begin_(first), it_end_(last) { } 
};

template <typename iter_type>
entity<iter_type> make_entity(iter_type first, iter_type last)
{
   return entity<iter_type>(first, last);
}
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::vector<double> my_vec {1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0};
   auto my_entity1 = make_entity(std::begin(my_vec), std::end(my_vec));
   // do stuff with entity

   std::map<int, double> my_map;
   auto my_entity2 = make_entity(std::begin(my_map), std::end(my_map));
   // do stuff with entity

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

To make sure that the iterator is a forward iterator and the contained type is `double`, you can use:

```
template <typename T> struct is_type_double : public std::false_type {};
template <> struct is_type_double<double> : public std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_type_double<double&> : public std::true_type {};

template <typename iter_type>
class entity {
   iter_type it_begin_;
   iter_type it_end_;

   public:
   entity(iter_type first, iter_type last) 
      : it_begin_(first), it_end_(last)
   {
      static_assert(is_type_double<decltype(*first)>::value, "Problem.");
   } 
};

template <typename iter_type>
entity<iter_type> make_entity(iter_type first, iter_type last)
{
   return entity<iter_type>(first, last);
}
```

With that, you can use:

```
std::vector<double> my_vec {1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 8.0, 2.0};
auto my_entity1 = make_entity(std::begin(my_vec), std::end(my_vec));
```

You will get a compile time error if you use:

```
std::map<int, double> my_map;
auto my_entity2 = make_entity(std::begin(my_map), std::end(my_map));
```

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at my EDIT 2? I want to specify that the iterator is a forward iterator and dereferencing it returns a `double`. So, in the case of your answer, I would like the second example to not work. (Apologies for not explicitly stating that, I thought that the code example showed it).